# Truncating a double to a float in C

Tags: c, floating-point, double, precision, floating-accuracy

This a very simple question, but an important one since it affects my whole project tremendously.

Suppose I have the following code snipet:

```
unsigned int x = 0xffffffff;
float f = (float)((double)x * (double)2.328306436538696e-010); //  x/2^32
```

I would expect that `f` be something like 0.99999, but instead, it rounds up to 1, since it's the closest `float` approximation. That's not good since I need `float` values on the interval of [0,1), not [0,1]. I'm sure it's something simple, but I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My eventual solution was to just shrink the size of my constant multiplier. It was probably the best solution since there was no point in multiplying by a double anyway. The precision was not seen after conversion to a float.

so `2.328306436538696e-010` was changed to `2.3283063`

Answer (score 8):

In C (since C99), you can change the rounding direction with [fesetround](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feround) from `libm`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fenv.h>
int main()
{
    #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
    fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
    // volatile -- uncomment for GNU gcc and whoever else doesn't support FENV
    unsigned long x = 0xffffffff;
    float f = (float)((double)x * (double)2.328306436538696e-010); //  x/2^32
    printf("%.50f\n", f);
}
```

Tested with IBM XL, Sun Studio, clang, GNU gcc. This gives me `0.99999994039535522460937500000000000000000000000000` in all cases

Comment: Is this a C++11 function?

Comment: @MarkB C99 function, included in C++11

Comment: Would it be possible to make this code put the rounding direction back immediately after doing the conversion?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan of course, I was only showing a minimal example

Answer (score 3):

The value above which a `double` rounds to 1 or more when converted to `float` in the default IEEE 754 rounding mode is `0x1.ffffffp-1` (in C99's hexadecimal notation, since your question is tagged “C”).

Your options are:

1. turn the FPU rounding mode to round-downward before the conversion, or
2. multiply by `(0x1.ffffffp-1 / 0xffffffffp0)` (give or take one ULP) to exploit the full single-precision range [0, 1) without getting the value `1.0f`.

Method 2 [leads to use the constant](http://ideone.com/gRbhdG) `0x1.ffffff01fffffp-33`:

```
double factor = nextafter(0x1.ffffffp-1 / 0xffffffffp0, 0.0);
unsigned int x = 0xffffffff;
float f = (float)((double)x * factor);
printf("factor:%a\nunrounded:%a\nresult:%a\n", factor, (double)x * factor, f);
```

Prints:

```
factor:0x1.ffffff01fffffp-33
unrounded:0x1.fffffefffffffp-1
result:0x1.fffffep-1
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not much you can do - your `int` holds 32 bits but the mantissa of a `float` holds only 24. Rounding is going to happen. You could change the processor rounding mode to round down instead of to nearest, but that is going to cause some side effects that you want to avoid especially if you don't restore the rounding mode when you are finished.

There's nothing wrong with the formula you're using, it's producing the most accurate answer possible for the given input. There's just an end case that's failing a hard requirement. There's nothing wrong with testing for the specific end case and replacing it with the closest value that meets the requirement:

```
if (f >= 1.0f)
    f = 0.99999994f;
```

0.999999940395355224609375 is the closest value that an IEEE-754 float can take without being equal to 1.0.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer. As other answers have shown (and they have shown how), there are things you can do.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, how is it not helpful? It provides a working solution to the problem, without leaving a rounding mode in effect which will change all intermediate and subsequent calculations.

Comment: The statement “There’s not much you can do” is misleading and needlessly discouraging. The statement about bits in an `int` and a `float` is irrelevant; the OP does not expect an exact map. They are not asking to avoid rounding, just to control it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I asserted that there will be rounding because the problem definition makes it unavoidable, and I gave my reasoning. You can change the nature of the rounding but you can't avoid it. Mine is the only answer which handles the edge case while maintaining the highest possible accuracy in all other cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could just truncate the value to maximum precision (keeping the 24 high bits) and divide by 2^24 to get the closest value a float can represent without being rounded to 1;

```
unsigned int i = 0xffffffff;
float value = (float)(i>>8)/(1<<24);

printf("%.20f\n", value);
printf("%a\n", value);

>>> 0.99999994039535522461
>>> 0x1.fffffep-1
```

Comment: This may be a good approach, if rounding every value toward zero (not just the ones near 1) suits the OP. The hack for illustration is unnecessary; we can use the `%a` format specifier to display floating-point numbers in a way that illustrates their composition.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for the `%a` format, did not know about that.